# Group values by sub string in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this documents in my collection :

```
{_id: "aaaaaaaa", email: "mail1@orange.fr"},
{_id: "bbbbbbbb", email: "mail2@orange.fr"},
{_id: "cccccccc", email: "mail3@orange.fr"},
{_id: "dddddddd", email: "mail4@gmail.com"},
{_id: "eeeeeeee", email: "mail5@gmail.com"},
{_id: "ffffffff", email: "mail6@yahoo.com"}
```

And i would like this result :

```
{
    result: [
        {domain: "orange.fr", count: 3},
        {domain: "gmail.com", count: 2},
        {domain: "yahoo.com", count: 1},
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure you can use the aggregator and $regex operator

Comment: Did you already tried something?

Comment: No, i no idea after reading the aggregator documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Aggregation Framework

I don't believe that with the present document structure you can achieve the desired result by using the aggregation framework. If you stored the domain name in a separate field, it would have become trivial:

```js
db.items.aggregate(
{
    $group:
    {
        _id: "$emailDomain",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    },
}
)
```

## Map-Reduce

It's possible to implement what you want using a simple map-reduce aggregation. Naturally, the performance will not be good on large collections.

#### Query

```js
db.emails.mapReduce(
    function() {
        if (this.email) {
            var parts = this.email.split('@');
            emit(parts[parts.length - 1], 1);
        }
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    {
        out: { inline: 1 }
    }
)
```

#### Output

```js
[
    {
        "_id" : "gmail.com",
        "value" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : "yahoo.com",
        "value" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : "orange.fr",
        "value" : 3
    }
]
```

Comment: a dedicated field is an evoked idea. But I wanted to do a test without. Thanks for the second solution.

Comment: Maybe not directly related but helpful if you came here and use DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility) instead of "native" MongoDB: DocumentDB doesn't support MapReduce at the time of writing so you will have to go with the aggregation framework and separate fields.

Answer (score 3):

**Aggregation Framework**

MongoDB 3.4(Released Nov 29, 2016) onwords in aggregation framework have many methods

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            domain: {
                $substr: ["$email", {
                    $indexOfBytes: ["$email", "@"]
                }, {
                    $strLenBytes: "$email"
                }]
            }
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$domain',
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'count': -1
        }
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            result: {
                $push: {
                    'domain': "$_id",
                    'count': '$count'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Results**

```
{
    _id: null,
    result: [
        {domain: "@orange.fr", count: 3},
        {domain: "@gmail.com", count: 2},
        {domain: "@yahoo.com", count: 1},
    ]
}
```